# Remove topic name from S3 paths when using Kafka Connect S3 Sink

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html

How would I set up the connector so that the Kafka topic names are not included in the output S3 paths?

I'm using the `TimeBasedPartitioner` and I'd like to have a fixed name in the path instead of the topic name. So this:

`fixed_name/<encodedPartition>/<topic>+<kafkaPartition>+<startOffset>.<format>`

Instead of the default:

`topics/<topic>/<encodedPartition>/<topic>+<kafkaPartition>+<startOffset>.<format>`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the topic name unless you write your own `Partitioner` and overwrite [`generatePartitionedPath`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/search?q=generatePartitionedPath&unscoped_q=generatePartitionedPath)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround by using `..` in partition path.
E.g.: Set `path.format='../day'=YYYY-MM-dd` to skip `topics` in the path, thus
`/topics/topic1/../day=2023-11-14` will be written to `/topics/day=2023-11-14`.